# I set date format as dd/MM/yyyy to display dd/MM/yyyy for datepicker but control validation does not validate as dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: angular-material

I set date format as dd/MM/yyyy for datepicker.
When I select the date, it shows the date as expected.
Now I added a custom validation to validate manual input.

**What I tried**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aiakxq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

I don't add a custom validation to formcontrol.

```
this.control = new FormControl(null);
```

And I create a method to show error message against the datepicker input (#pickerInput).

```
  <input matInput
         [matDatepicker]="picker"
         [formControl]="control"
         #pickerInput/>
  <mat-hint>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="control?.invalid">{{getErrorMessage(pickerInput.value)}}</mat-error>
```

And getErrorMessage is

```
    getErrorMessage(input: string) {
    if (input) {
      const regexPattern =
        /^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$/;
      const isValid = regexPattern.test(input);
      if (!isValid) {
        this.control?.setErrors({ invalidDateFormat: true });
        this.control?.updateValueAndValidity();
        return 'Invalid Date Format';
      } else {
        this.control?.setErrors({ invalidDateFormat: null });
        this.control?.updateValueAndValidity();
        return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Steps:

1. When I selected a date from calendar, it shows the date as expected.

[image]

2. I delete the last number. The error shows as expected.

[image]

3. I added the number back. The error message has gone but the field is marked as red.

[image]

I think the datepicker value is validated as MM/dd/yyyy? The control has an error.

```
{ "matDatepickerParse": { "text": "24/04/2023" } }
```

Comment: Do you assign any validation Rules to the Control, somewhare later, because this is either an update problem or some validation you are not showing of (at least I'd guess so)